# How often does a browsers memory of the htaccess/htpasswd password reset?

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm making a games website for me and my friends. Its just a load of flash files dumped in a folder. I want to password protect this folder.

so my question is, how long does the browser remember the password?

take into consideration that all (afaik) the school pcs are on the same external ip.(although I don't think it would be stored server side) All use internet explorer and everyone has their own account.
Also, I don't plan on being the only one using it, my friends will etc, so i can't rely on things like private browsing.

I would be happy for the login to reset on browser reset or windows login, If neither of these are default how could i achieve them?

Comment: which browser? This question might be closed if you don't give a little more info

Comment: Depends. Use *"Private Browsing"* (should isolate browser session) and *Logout of the OS/Shell* (hopefully everyone has their own account! but at the very least this will terminate the interactive desktop session and associated resources) to mitigate/eliminate cross-access. Also, if possible, consider a "portable browser" executed from a thumbdrive (*this is not always allowed* but it could eliminate persisting temporary data on the primary storage).